# Acknowledgment part of manuscript before submission

Tags: paper-submission, acknowledgement

I am going to submit a manuscript to a journal. Should the acknowledgment section be written after the acceptance of the article or it can be written in the first step of submission? In my case, I would like to express my appreciation to a professor that I had some useful discussion with him, in that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably doesn't matter as it is unlikely that it would be of concern to the reviewers. But there is no reason to withhold it either. Yes, it can be submitted in the first submission.

An exception might be if you were hiding the identity of a person who might possibly be a reviewer and the editor didn't know the connection, but for an advisor this isn't a likely scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I've always included the acknowledgements section in the initial submission. For journals in my field, it is more or less required because certain disclosures like funding sources occur in that area. It's also a hint to the editor that the people acknowledged are likely too close to the work to serve as impartial peer reviewers.

For journal manuscripts, it would be unusual to me to acknowledge someone for anything besides contribution to the manuscript at hand that does not rise to the level of authorship. In contrast, in a thesis it's normal to include personal notes of appreciation (though this may vary by country/field). So, if your professor has contributed to this manuscript in some way, such as by providing advice or suggestions to the manuscript, it's appropriate to express your appreciation for those contributions and it's appropriate to do so in the initial submission.